# get jclass from jfieldID

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jvmti

I want to iterate over all field values of an object of a given class using JNI. I found the JVMTI method `GetClassFields` to get the `jfieldID`s of the fields of an object. In the JNI API I found the methods `Get<type>Field`. However, to use these methods I first have to know if I'm dealing with one of the primitives, arrays of a certain type, or objects. I found a JNI method `ToReflectedField` so I could call the Java methods of the reflection API. However, this seems overly complicated and error prone.

Is there a way to achieve this with native functions of JNI or JVMTI?

Comment: Why? You can do all this directly in Java. No JNI or JVMTI required at all.

Comment: I want to copy an object and all its references to the "native heap" to be invisible for the GC. If there is no easy way to achieve this with JNI or JVMTI I will implement the iterating part in Java. I just thought the code would be easier to understand if I have both the iterating and copying part on the native side.

Comment: I would venture to say that *no* Java code is easier to understand on the native side :)

Comment: GetClassFields requires jclass. Do you want to drop it and get a new jclass instance from a jfieldID?

Comment: In my use case, the jclass is the root class from which I want to determine the classes of the potentially referenced objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JVMTI to get the type of every field and then call the respective GetField method:

```
jvmtiError
GetFieldName(jvmtiEnv* env,
        jclass klass,
        jfieldID field,
        char** name_ptr,
        char** signature_ptr,
        char** generic_ptr)
```